# Azure devops - GIT - Command Line vs PowerShell Task - %2 is getting removed from the URL in command line task but works in PS

Tags: git, azure, powershell, command-line, azure-devops

Using the below works when I use a PS Task in the ADO build pipeline but the same fails in Command line task.

```
git push https://PAT@dev.azure.com/MyORG/Work%20Management/_git/Work%20Mgmt%20-%20ME
```

Failure shown in Cmd Line Task:

```
##[error]remote: TF200016: The following project does not exist: Work0Management. Verify that the name of the project is correct and that the project exists on the specified Azure DevOps Server.
fatal: repository 'https://dev.azure.com/MyORG/Work0Management/_git/Work0Mgmt0-0ME/' not found
```

It seems `%2` is being removed from the URL.

I tried using `@'URL'` but that fails with fatal: protocol `'@'https'` is not supported error.

Should we prefer PS over Command line tasks in ADO ?  Note:  I have few other issues with our existing build agents when using PS and hence I am planning to use the CML task for the git activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the occurrence of **%20** with **%%20**. The command shell is interpreting **%2** as an argument that is empty. That leaves **0**.